# How do I change the horizontal spacing within entries of ListofFigures and Bibliography?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

My thesis requires that I have double spacing throughout the document, except "within entries of the list of figures, tables, and Bibliography."

The school template set the spacing this way in the .cls file:

```
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{%
  \let\CS=\small\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\CS}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{%
  \let\CS=\small\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}\CS}
```

So that I can just type in the .tex files by

```
\doublespacing
```

How do I modify the entries then?

My document:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\makeabstract

\doublespacing

...
...

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

...
...

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{lit}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just add  `\singlespacing` before `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: ... I feel so stupid now ... it worked but I didn't understand why. I had assumed doing \singlespacing would change the spacing between entries too...